# Fast Modem Speeds... But slow Router Speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I started to have problems with my internet speeds. I am paying for 100 mbps but I am only getting about 10 mbps from the router. If I connect my computer directly to the modem I will get about 97 mbps. I've bought a new router and still have the same problem. It is a Netgear WNDR4500. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Is there any way that I can change the 802.11 mode? Right now it is b/n/g...

Comment: This is very interesting. I was using a WNDR3400 for many years, and had recently run into greatly reduced bandwidth, basically same as you have. I upgraded to a new WNDR4500 and now have blazing speed. So, it didn't work for you? Are you absolutely certain you are connecting to the new router? For instance, did you leave the old router plugged in while testing? You have ruled out the modem being the bottleneck. The only other possibility is your wireless card. Not sure how to test that except on another network.

Comment: I did turn off the old router. And I power cycled the new router, and the modem. The only thing I can think of is the 802.11 mode is what is causing it. But I can't figure out how to change it on the Netgear homepage

Comment: Is it possible you have your wireless card to operate in some kind of powersaving mode?

Comment: Why exactly is getting 97% throughput a problem?  Take a look at your service agreement with your ISP.  I guarantee you are not promised 100 mbps 24/7/365 when downloading from every source.  As for the 10 mbps problem that is easily explained.

Comment: What type of 802.11 does your client device support? Are you using WPA2 (AES-CCMP) security on wireless? Do you have WMM enabled? Are you on a clean channel (don't forget to take non-802.11 interference into account)? Are you reasonably close to the router? What performance do you get when wired to a LAN port of the router?

Comment: My client device is using 802.11n and I am using WPA2 security. I don't think I have WMM enabled and I have my router set on channel 4. As for the distance, I am in a 2 story house, but if I am 2 ft away I will get 30mbps wireless speeds. But if I move a little more to about 10ft the speeds will drop to about 10mbps. When I am connected directly to the router by wire I am getting about 80mbps.

Answer (score 0):

By far the most likely fault is a poor cable between the router and the modem. If cabling is poor it will fall back from 100Mbps to 10Mbps and thus decimate your speed.

Using a correct patch cable and this will instantly resolve. If thats not it, then I suspect you're experiencing a wireless issue and need to follow regular troubleshooting for that.

Comment: I got a new cat6 cable and I used that to connect the modem to the router and I got a cat5 cable and connected the router directly to my desktop and it gave me the 100mbps speeds. But I did a speed test with an iphone right next to the router and I only got 16mbps.